# Ways to terminate a sentence in a c++?

Tags: c++

I'm beginner to Cpp and trying to go through the examples given a book named "Programming Principles and Practice using c++" (2nd edition).

For further reference I'm talking about the "4.6.4 A text example" where a sentence needs to be taken as an input and build a dictionary of words (after sorting).

The example which was mentioned was like the below.

```
// simple dictionary: list of sorted words
int main()
{
  vector<string> words;
  for(string temp; cin>>temp; ) // read whitespace-separated words
     words.push_back(temp); // put into vector
  cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << '\n';
  sort(words); // sort the words
  for (int i = 0; i<words.size(); ++i)
     if (i==0 || words[i–1]!=words[i]) // is this a new word?
        cout << words[i] << "\n";
}
```

In the above code sample line number 5 (in the for loop expression), the cin >> temp didn't make sense to me. Why? After running the code the console popped up and I started to enter the sentence with couple of words and even after hitting enter, I wasn't able to terminate the string and go to the next line? How to terminate inputs here?

Comment: Off-topic, but -- `if (i==0 || words[i–1]!=words[i])` will not work for something like `apple banana apple banana`.  The easiest solution is to use a `std::set<std::string>`, since not only does it sort, it only stores unique items.

Comment: Currently the stream has to fail to read to exit the loop. When reading into a `std::string` this is pretty hard to do without closing the input stream. Depending on the terminal software being used that can be done with CTRL+D xor CTRL+Z on most desktop platforms. Note that once close it may be difficult to open `cin` again.

Comment: Typically what I do is something like [option 2 in this linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/4581301). Read the whole line from the input stream, write that line into second stream. Loop through the second stream. At the end of the line, the second stream ends, exiting the loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: you missed `sort(words);`.

Comment: Alternative would be pipe: `cat some_file | your_app`

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, I missed it.  Still, using `std::set<std::string>` would eliminate the need for `sort()` or the subsequent `for` loop.

Comment: Minor danger: the `–` in `words[i–1]` is ***not*** a minus sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the program is currently written, the stream has to fail to read to exit the loop. When reading into a `std::string` this is pretty hard to do, `string` will gleefully eat just about anything, without closing the input stream. Depending on the terminal software being used, closing the stream can be done with CTRL+D xor CTRL+Z on most desktop platforms.

Note that once closed, it may be difficult to open `cin` again, so typically what I do is something like [option 2 in this linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/4581301). Read the whole line from the input stream, write that line into second stream. Loop through the second stream. At the end of the line, the second stream ends, exiting the loop.

A trivial multiline version of the original code could look like

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(cin, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line); // #include <sstream>
        vector<string> words;
        for(string temp; iss>>temp; ) // read whitespace-separated words
            words.push_back(temp); // put into vector

        cout << "Number of words: " << words.size() << '\n';
        sort(words); // sort the words
        for (int i = 0; i<words.size(); ++i)
            if (i==0 || words[i-1]!=words[i]) // is this a new word?
                cout << words[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, although some advanced topics like stringstreams were used, but I got a picture that the example mentioned in the book at this point of time cannot terminate a string without additional help like the code you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

> the cin >> temp didn't make sense to me. Why?

```
  for(string temp; cin>>temp; ) // read whitespace-separated words
     words.push_back(temp); // put into vector
```

It's equivalent to:

```
string temp;
while (cin >> temp)
{
    words.push_back(temp);
}
```

`cin>>temp` will evaluate to `false` when the end of the input stream is reached and trigger the loop to break out.  Otherwise, `temp` is assigned a string and `cin>>temp` evaluates to true.

Comment: the info OP is missing is: Whats the en of the input stream? What do they need to enter?

Comment: If it's a redirected file from the command line, then nothing. If it's from the console, then I believe it's CTRL+Z on Windows and CTRL+D on Unix/Mac.

Answer (score 1):

The `>>` operator is an [overloaded function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2).

What's really being called in `operator>>(cin, temp)`.

The function returns the stream (`cin`) itself which have an overloaded [`bool` conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), which returns `true` if the stream state is fine. It returns `false` on failure, like for example end-of-file.

Which means the stream and the input operators can be used as part of a boolean condition to read until you reach end-of-file.

Comment: same comment here: The info OP is missing is: What is end-of-file when they type at the console? What to enter?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: This example is copy pasted (nothing was changed) and the author (c++ inventor) tried to explain what happens after the example is executed. In the book, somehow it got terminated but when I  try the same code, it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

`cin >> temp` will evaluate to `false` if the input operation fails.  The most common failure when reading into a `string` is to reach the end-of-file, and that's the condition you want to cause.

On most Linux (or other POSIX) shells, the way to input an end-of-file marker is to press `ctrl+d`.  In the Windows console host it's `ctrl+x`.

Alternatively, instead of interacting directly with the program, you can hook its input up to the output of some other command using a pipeline.  When the command generating output terminates and closes its end of the pipe your program will see an end-of-file condition.  For example, something like this would work on pretty much any shell:

```bash
echo "this is some text" | your-program
```

Or, using most modern POSIX shells, you could use a heredoc.  This works basically the same as above, but the shell itself writes to your program's input stream instead of hooking up an external command to do so:

```bash
your-program <<EOF
this is some text
EOF
```

Comment: I will save this answer, might be helpful in the future. thank you.